# Limited color choice in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

Matplotlib is a very good package for 2D plotting in python (It says by using it you can generate production-quality graphs), but when I used it to plot bar charts, I was very disappinted with its limited color resourses. As far as I know, only seven kinds of colors were included, namely blue, cyan, green, black, magenta, red, white and yellow. Can anybody tell me if there are other kinds of colors or just those i listed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) "In addition [to those seven colors], you can specify colors in many weird and wonderful ways, including full names ('green'), hex strings ('#008000'), RGB or RGBA tuples ((0,1,0,1)) or grayscale intensities as a string ('0.8')." You can do this using the kwarg `color`.

Here's an example:

```
from matplotlib.pylab import plot, show, hold
from numpy.random import rand

hold(True)
plot(rand(10,1), color = ((0.1,0.5,0.2)))
plot(rand(10,1), color = '#400000')
plot(rand(10,1), color = '0.8')
show()
```

[image: plot with various colors]

Comment: also see `matplotlib.colors.cnames` which is a ~147 element dictionary which maps names -> hex strings.